# Mercurial - hg log for just two changesets?

Tags: mercurial, hg-log

The command `hg log -v -r 2:5` can be used to see details on changesets 2/3/4/5 - is there a similar way you can view changeset details on JUST changesets 2 and 5?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use separate `-r` specifiers:

```
hg log -v -r 2 -r 5
```

It will give you the log entries in the same order you specify rev numbers.

Here's a test which demonstrates this:

```
mkdir hgTest; cd hgTest; hg init; echo "0" > 0.txt; hg addremove; hg commit -m "Added file 0.txt"; echo "1" > 1.txt; hg addremove; hg commit -m "Added file 1.txt"; echo "2" > 2.txt; hg addremove; hg commit -m "Added file 2.txt"
```

Now run `hg log -v -r 0 -r 2` in the hgTest directory, and you'll see:

```
changeset:   0:22deafd4b5da
user:        aUser
date:        Fri Mar 25 17:37:01 2011 +0000
files:       0.txt
description:
Added file 0.txt


changeset:   2:39fedf6f9f56
tag:         tip
user:        aUser
date:        Fri Mar 25 17:37:01 2011 +0000
files:       2.txt
description:
Added file 2.txt
```

Notice there's no mention of the file `1.txt` which was added in revision 1.

Comment: I believe this will compare all repository changes between 2 and 5 but we are only interested in changes for files that were checked in as part of 2 and 5 - not files which were only included in changesets 3 and 4

Comment: No, it gives you the changed files in those revisions only. Try it and see, it only takes a few seconds to make a new repository and do a few test commits.

Comment: Ok, have added an example to my answer.